# Iterate For loop for specific time line

Tags: java

I am new to java development, I have bit doubt on how to slow down the for loop. I have set of list counts, and i iterate those using for loop. i want to iterate the count for certain time limit. (ie) the iterating time between count 1 and two should be delayed for 2 sec. is this possible to do. Pl guide me on this

Comment: Do you mean like `Thread.sleep(2000);` ?

Comment: based on what I understood of your question, Peter's answer is right...

Comment: yes. For iterate between the counts should be delayed. but i am not sure this will be possible with thread. Can you pl explain in breif

Comment: @Peter Lawrey, +1 but I put my version as an answer. Sorry for being such a "rep slut" ;-)

Comment: @Bathsheba No worry, I have more than I can spend. ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            try {
                System.out.println(i);
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } //System.out.println(stem[0]);
            catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication2.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
```

Comment: You could just have main `throws InterruptedException` and drop the try/catch block.

Answer (score 4):

The clearest way I can think of is to use

```
java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
Thread.sleep(time); //time in milliseconds, in your case it is 2000
```